# Retain socket connection in activity android

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service

I'm trying to create a service which controls the socket connection between client and server, to retain socket connection between activities of the client. This client's process is when user clicks on a connect button, a socket will be created and the client'll move to next activity, in this activity I created a button to send data to the server using the newly created socket. But the server seems not receive any data from the client when clicking this button.
Here is my Service

```
//ConnectionService.java
public class ConnectionService extends Service {
...
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public ConnectionService getService(){
        return ConnectionService.this;
    }
}
private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myBinder;
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("Socket connection","I am on onCreate()");
}

public void isBoundable(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Boundable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void getSocketInfo(){
    Log.i("Socket info",socket.toString());
}

public void sendMessage(String message){
    if(dos!=null){
        Log.i("Data_Transfer","Sending message");
        try {
            dos.writeUTF(message);
            dos.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Data_Transfer","Message sent");
    }
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    //Log.i("Socket connection","I am in onStartCommand");
    Runnable connection = new SocketConnection();
    new Thread(connection).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

class SocketConnection implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //create socket connection
        try {
            //Log.i("Socket connection", "C: connecting");
            serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, SERVER_PORT);
            //Log.i("Socket connection", "C: connected");

            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            Log.i("TCP client","C: sent");
            dos.writeUTF("Message from client");
            dos.flush();

            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String msg = "";
            msg=dis.readUTF();
            Log.d("response",msg);

        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("TCP client","Cannot connect to server");
        }
    }
}
```

Activity created the service:

```
private ConnectionService boundService;
private Boolean isBound;

private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service){
        Log.i("Connect","Creating service");
        boundService = ((ConnectionService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
        if(boundService!=null){
            Log.i("Connect","service bounded");
            boundService.isBoundable();
            responseFromServerView.setText("Connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name){

        boundService = null;

    }

};

private void doBindService(){
    bindService(new Intent(ShareImages.this,ConnectionService.class),connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    isBound = true;
}

private void doUnbindService(){
    if(isBound){
        unbindService(connection);
        isBound = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    doUnbindService();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share_images);

    responseFromServerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.responseFromServer);
    responseFromServerView.setText("Connecting");
    sendDataBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendDataBtn);
    sendDataBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(boundService!=null){
                boundService.getSocketInfo();
                boundService.sendMessage("New message");
                Log.i("Connect","Sent");
            }
            Toast.makeText(ShareImages.this, "Sent to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    startService(new Intent(ShareImages.this, ConnectionService.class));
    doBindService();

}
```

Server code:

```
private class SocketServerThread implements Runnable {

    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                            + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                }
            });

            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                String messageFromClient = "";

                //If no message sent from client, this code will block the program
                messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                count++;
                message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                        + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n"
                        + "Msg from client: " + messageFromClient + "\n";

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });

                String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + count;
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgReply);
                System.out.println(messageFromClient);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            final String errMsg = e.toString();
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    msg.setText(errMsg);
                }
            });

        }
```

When "Connect to server" is pressed, the client sends message "Message from client" to server, and it works, server can receive this message. But after the connection, in the new activity, press another button to send "New message" string to server doesn't work, server doesn't receive the message, even when the boundService still exists. Anyone please help me to fix this.
P/S: is it the correct way to make a server handle multiple clients and a client which needs to retain the socket connection all the time??

Comment: Did you check `logcat`?

Comment: Yes, server didn't receive the "New message”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server implementation is not correct. After accepting connection your server should spawn a new thread and pass the socket returned by accept to it. This thread should then communicate with client as needed.
Your current implementation accepts a connection, reads first message from client and then loop returns to 'accept'.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.  But I suspect your service is running the same process as your Activity (and might not matter if it's not).

So when this code is invoked via the onClick listener:

```
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if(dos!=null){
        Log.i("Data_Transfer","Sending message");
        try {
            dos.writeUTF(message);
            dos.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Data_Transfer","Message sent");
    }
}
```

The `dos.write` call throws an IOException because you are attempting to do a blocking network call on the UI thread.